# What is the smallest integer $N>2$, such that $x^5+y^5 = N$ has a rational solution?

Tags: number-theory, rational-numbers

I was considering the Fermat-like equation,
$$a^k + N b^k = c^k$$

which, for odd power $k$, is equivalent to
$$x^k+y^k = N\tag1$$

and rational $x,y$.

> **Q:** For a given $k$, what is the smallest integer $N$ such that $(1)$ has a solution with ***rational*** ($\color{red}{not}$ integer) $x,y$?

---

For $k=3$, and appealing to the theory of elliptic curves, [it is $N=6$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287983/sum-of-cubes-of-two-rationals):

$$\bigl(\tfrac{17}{21}\bigr)^3+\bigl(\tfrac{37}{21}\bigr)^3 = 6$$
$$\bigl(\tfrac{-1805723 }{960540 }\bigr)^3+\bigl(\tfrac{2237723 }{960540 }\bigr)^3 = 6$$

For $k=5$, it *seems* to be the horribly large $N=68101$:

$$\bigl(\tfrac{15}{2}\bigr)^5+\bigl(\tfrac{17}{2}\bigr)^5 = 68101$$

However, my search radius was very limited, with numerator and denominator $<500$. As the second example for $k=3$ shows, it may not been large enough. So what really is $N$ for $k=5$?

Comment: So you explicitly disallow integer solutions? Otherwise you trivially get $2^5+1^5=33$.

Comment: @Wojowu: Yes, to be analogous with $N=6$. I made sure to highlight it in red. :)

Comment: @Wojowu: If I allow integers, the smallest for ***any*** $k$ is $N=2$ and deflates the question.

Comment: See http://oeis.org/A111152; it claims $N = 68101$.

Comment: There is a proof by Seiji Tomita at http://www.maroon.dti.ne.jp/fermat/dioph64e.html. Someone who can verify it should post it as an answer.

Comment: I currently looking at a problem that may be related, for $k=6$. I’ll look at this next.

Comment: @OldPeter: It turns out Tomita has investigated this though.

Comment: @RicardoBuring: Thanks for the reference. With remarks, it is enough as a preliminary answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to R. Buring's comment, it turns out [A111152](http://oeis.org/A111152) has,

$$(17/21)^3 + (37/21)^3 = 6$$

$$(25/17)^4 + (149/17)^4 = 5906 $$

$$(15/2)^5 + (17/2)^5 = 68101$$

with D. Winter remarking in a 2001 [sci.math post](http://oeis.org/A111152/a111152.txt) that "...*it is known 68101 is the smallest n for k = 5*".$^\text{his reference?}$

---

For higher powers $k$, it seems it depends on $k \equiv \text{mod}\, 4$. Seiji Tomita has conjectured that for $m\geq1$,

$$n=\Bigl(\tfrac{2^{4m}-1}{2}\Bigr)^{4m+1}+\Bigl(\tfrac{2^{4m}+1}{2}\Bigr)^{4m+1}$$

$$n=\Bigl(\tfrac{p}{5}\Bigr)^{4m+2}+\Bigl(\tfrac{q}{5}\Bigr)^{4m+2}$$

$$n=\Bigl(\tfrac{2^{4m+2}-1}{2}\Bigr)^{4m+3}+\Bigl(\tfrac{2^{4m+2}+1}{2}\Bigr)^{4m+3}$$

and where $p+q\,i =(2+i)^k$ for appropriate $k\leq4m+2$.

---

The difficult case is $k=4m$. Tomita found,

$$(25/17)^4 + (149/17)^4\\
 (50429/17)^8 + (43975/17)^8\\
 (9298423/17)^{12} + (8189146/17)^{12}$$

though the numerators apparently are not as well-behaved as $p,q$.