# Parametric solutions $ax^4+by^4=cz^4$

Tags: diophantine-equations

Fermat proved that $x^4+y^4=z^4$ has no non-trivial solutions. I am sure that the diophantine equation below does have integer solutions if $a=b=c\neq \pm 1$
$$ax^4+by^4=cz^4$$
Now can one tell me how I can get all the possible integer solutions?

Comment: This isn't that easy as it looks. For the very first equation , there are no solutions, by FLT

Comment: There will be special triples for $(a,b,c)$ for which solutions exist Eg $(2,3,5)$ trivially ... more generally you will probably need to analyse on a case by case basis ... do you have any results about this yourself ?

Comment: Typo ... ? Fermat proved that $x^4+y^4=z^4$ **doesn't have** non-trivial solutions ...

Comment: As an indication of how hard this is, a question about the special case $(a,b,c)=(1,5,1)$ (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2025355/diophantine-equation-x45y4-z4#comment4163557_2025355) remains unanswered after more than 3 months.

Answer (score 2):

$ax^4+by^4=cz^4$ has parametric solution given below:

$$(a,b,c)=[(x^2),(2y^2-3x^2),(x^2+2y^2)]$$

Above has condition:   $(z^2=y^2-x^2)$

Numerical solution for $(x,y,z)=(5,13,12)$ is given below,

$25(5)^4+263(13)^4=363(12)^4$

Answer (score 1):

Theorem about absence of non-trivial solutions of equation
$$x^4 + y^4 = z^4$$
is a partial case of Fermat Last Theorem for exponent 4. It is a consequence of the single Fermat theorem with [published author's prove](https://arxiv.org/abs/0902.3623).

The original question is too general for a clear answer.