# Show that $3x^4+4y^4=19z^4$ has no integer solution

Tags: diophantine-equations, quartics

If $x,y,z$ are integers such that $xyz\neq 0$, prove or disprove that
$$3x^4+4y^4=19z^4$$
has no solution.

Maybe this is can use quadratic residue to solve it, maybe this equation seem is famous? because I have solve paper Introduced [this](https://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/48054/13_2005_Article_BF01196658.pdf;jsessionid=F0C64CDCB874D8359C7768D916C4B22B?sequence=1).

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2164195/parametric-solutions-ax4by4-cz4), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2025355/diophantine-equation-x45y4-z4#comment4163557_2025355).

Comment: what did you try? any thoughts?

Comment: Now I have add edit my some try,

Comment: This is an article, but not your try.

Comment: @DietrichBurde,No I think it's diffenert $a,b,c$ the problem hard not

Comment: The equation $ax^p+by^q=cz^r$ is called generalized Fermat equation. Here we have $1/p+1/q+1/r=3/4<1$, and $gcd(a,b,c)=1$, so that we have at most finitely many integer solutions.

Comment: My program checked values $(y,z)$ of $[1.. 38967, 1.. 26395]$ and found no solutions.

Comment: I tried to show that the equality has only zero solutions, looking for a number $p$ such that the equality modulo $p$ has only zero solutions. I found no such $p\in [2..1000]$.

Comment: The paper you linked to explicitly stated that there is no non-trivial solution to this equation, and it contains a **proof** of that, on page 345. What do you want then? Do you want someone to copy the proof there, or to explain it to you in detail?

Comment: The proof is there on pages 345 and 346  by considering the equation in an extension and showing that it has no rational solutions there, so what do you want? An explanation?

Comment: New version added.

Answer (score 4):

The equation is
$$
3x^4+4y^4=19z^4,\tag 1
$$
where $x,y,z$, integers. We also assume that
$$
xyz\neq 0\textrm{ and }(x,y,z)=1.\tag 2
$$

We write (1) in the form
$$
3x^4-3z^4=16z^4-4y^4.
$$
Hence
$$
3(x^2-z^2)(x^2+z^2)=4(2z^2-y^2)(2z^2+y^2)
$$
or equivalently
$$
N=3(x-z)(x+z)(x^2+z^2)=4(2z^2-y^2)(2z^2+y^2).
$$
Obviously $N\neq 0$ from (1) and (2). If $xyz\neq0$, then $x^2+z^2>1$ and $2z^2+y^2>1$ and $4|N$, $3|N$.

Also $x,z$ not both even (since $(x,y,z)=1$) and writing $x=2k+1$, $z=2l$, we get ($x^4=16k_1+1$):
$$
N=3(x^4-z^4)=3(16k_1+1-16l^4)=4(8l^2-y^2)(8l^2+y^2),
$$
which is imposible. The other case is if $x=2k$ and $z=2l+1$, then ($z^2=4l_1+1,z^4=16l_2+1$):
$$
N=3(x^4-z^4)=3(16k^4-16l_2-1)=4(8l_2+2-y^2)(8l_2+2+y^2),
$$
which is also imposible.

If $x,z$ both odd, then $x=2k+1$, $z=2l+1$, $8|\left(4(2z^2-y^2)(2z^2+y^2)\right)\Rightarrow 2|y$. Hence $y=2m$ and $x^2=8k_1+1$,$z^2=8l_1+1$, $x^4=16k_2+1,z^4=16l_2+1$. Hence $3(x^4-z^4)=3\cdot 16(k_2-l_2)=4(2(8l_1+1)-4m^2)(2(8l_1+1)+4m^2)\Rightarrow$ $3\cdot4(k_2-l_2)=(8l_1+2-4m^2)(8l_1+2+4m^2)\Rightarrow$ $3(k_2-l_2)=(4l_1+1-2m^2)(4l_1+1+2m^2)=(4l_1+1)^2-4m^4$.

But $k_2=4k_1^2+k_1$, $l_2=4l_1^2+l_1$. Hence  $(k_2-l_2)=4(k_1^2-l_1^2)+(k_1-l_1)$. If $k_1-l_1=1(mod4)$, then contradiction (easily). If $k_1-l_1=3(mod4)$, then I have make error in the proof and the problem is open. I hope in the next few days I find a proof.

Comment: @Nikos_Bagis I followed  your argument up until you said "which is easily seen to be impossible in the set of integers, since an even number divides an odd." I don't see why (2) forces us to divide an even number into an odd number. Maybe I'm not seeing something obvious, but I fail to see the impossibility from this argument.

Comment: @quantus 14. ok I will fix it

Comment: I have changed my first proof. Please correct me if Im  wrong, since diophantine equations is not a field I know very well.

Comment: @Nikos_Bagis This is much better! I realized from looking at your proof that the conclusion can be arrived at much quicker if you say that $4$ divides the right side of the alternative form of (1), then $4$ must also divide the left side. $x$ and $z$ have opposite parities which implies $4$ cannot divide $3x^4-3z^4$ QED. I didn't think it was possible to prove this problem with so little effort. (+1)

Comment: @quantus 14. Thanks

Comment: I believe it should be $16z^4-4y^4=4(2z^2-y^2)(2z^2+y^2)$.

Comment: at last step,  I think is wrong,because if $k_{1}-l_{1}\equiv 3\pmod 4$,then $k_{2}-l_{2}=4(k^2_{1}-l^2_{1})+(k_{1}-l_{1})=3\pmod 4$,so by $3(k_{2}-l_{2})=(4l_{1}+1)^2-4m^4$, you can't get imposible,because $LHS\equiv Right\equiv 1\pmod 4$.so you solution not wrong

Comment: @NikosBagis,is $4k^2_{1}-4l^2_{1}\equiv 0\pmod 4?$,so $k_{2}-l_{2}=(4k^2_{1}-4l^2_{1})+(k_{1}-l_{1})\equiv 0+(k_{1}-l_{1})\equiv 3\pmod 4?$

Comment: and you are wrong,if $k_{1}-l_{1}\equiv 3\pmod 4$,then $-3(k_{1}-l_{1})\equiv -3\cdot 3=-9\equiv -1\equiv 3\pmod 4$

Answer (score 3):

$\color{brown}{\textbf{Version of 07.10.19.}}$

Is known that the Diophantine equation

> $$uv=w^2,\quad (u,v,w)\in\mathbb N^3$$
>   has the common solution
>   $$u=k^2m,\quad v=l^2m,\quad w=klm,\quad \gcd(k,l)=1.$$

The issue equation can be presented in the form of
$$57(z^2-x^2)^2 + (8y^2)^2 = (3x^2-19z^2)^2,\tag1$$
or
$$57(z^2-x^2)^2 = (3x^2+8y^2-19z^2)(3x^2+8y^2-19z^2).\tag2$$
Equation
$$3x^2+8y^2\equiv 0\pmod{19}$$
has the single solution
$$x\equiv y \equiv 0\pmod{19}$$
(see also [Wolfram Alpha solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%7B%283m2%2B8n%5E2%29%20%20mod%2019%3D0%2C%20-1%3Cm%3C19%2C%20-1%3Cn%3C19%7D%20over%20integers)),

and equation
$$8y^2-19z^2\equiv 0\pmod{3}$$
has the single solution
$$y\equiv z \equiv 0\pmod{3}$$
(see also [Wolfram Alpha solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%7B%288m2-19n%5E2%29%20%20mod%203%3D0%2C%20-1%3Cm%3C3%2C%20-1%3Cn%3C3%7D%20over%20integers)).

Besides, from $(1)$ should $z>x,$ so
$$
\begin{cases}
-3x^2+8y^2+19z^2 = m^2s\\
-3x^2-8y^2+19z^2 = 57n^2s\\
z^2-x^2=mns\\
(m,n,s)\in\mathbb N^2\\
\gcd(m,n)=1
\end{cases}\Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
16y^2 = (m^2+57n^2)s\\
2(19z^2-3x^2) = (m^2-57n^2)s\\
z^2-x^2=mns\\
(m,n,s)\in\mathbb N^2\\
\gcd(m,n)=1
\end{cases}
$$
\begin{cases}
16y^2 = (m^2+57n^2)s\\
32z^2 = (m^2-6mn-57n^2)s\\
32x^2 = (m^2-38mn-57n^2)s\\
(m,n,s)\in\mathbb N^2\\
\gcd(m,n)=1\tag3.
\end{cases}

From $(3.1),(3.2)$ unknowns $m,n$ should have the same parity.

Let $m=n+2p,$ then
\begin{cases}
8y^2 = (2p^2+2pn+29n^2)s\\
8z^2 = (p^2-2pn-13n^2)s\\
8x^2 = (p^2-18pn-13n^2)s\\
(n,p,s)\in\mathbb N^2\\
\gcd(n,2p)=1\tag4.
\end{cases}

From $(4.1),(4.5)$ should $8\,|\,s.$

Let $s=8t,$ then
\begin{cases}
y^2 = (2p^2+2pn+29n^2)t\\
z^2 = (p^2-2pn-13n^2)t\\
x^2 = (p^2-18pn-13n^2)t\\
(n,p,t)\in\mathbb N^2\\
\gcd(n,2p)=1\tag5.
\end{cases}

Since 
$$g=\gcd(p^2-2pn-13n^2,p^2-18pn-13n^2)\,|\,16pn,$$
then $g=1,$
$$\gcd(t,p^2-2pn-13n^2,p^2-18pn-13n^2)\,|\,16pn,$$

so $t=T^2,$
\begin{cases}
2p^2+2pn+29n^2=Y^2\\
p^2-2pn-13n^2 = Z^2\\
p^2-18pn-13n^2 = X^2\\
(n,p,t)\in\mathbb N^2\\
\gcd(n,2p)=1\tag6.
\end{cases}

Equation $(6.3),(6.5)$ can be written in the form of
$$Z^2 + 14n^2 = (p-1)^2,\quad 2\,|\not\ n.$$
By the parity, $Z=p-1-2r,$ and the system
$$2r^2-2(p-1)r+7n^2 =0,\quad 2\,|\not\ n$$
**does not have solutions.**

---

$$$$
**Old version.**

Is known that the Diophantine equation

> $$kx^2+y^2=z^2,\quad (x,y,z,k)\in\mathbb N^4$$
>   with odd $k,$ has common solution
>   $$x=m(2n-1),\quad y=m\dfrac{(2n-1)^2-1}2,\quad z=m\dfrac{k(2n-1)^2+1}2,\quad (m,n)\in \mathbb N^2.$$

The issue equation can be presented in the form of
$$57(x^2-z^2)^2 + (8y^2)^2 = (3x^2-19z^2)^2,\tag1$$
with the common solution in the form of
$$\begin{cases}
x^2-z^2 = s^\,_1m(2n-1)\\
8y^2=m\dfrac{57(2n-1)2-1}2\\
3x^2-19z^2=s^\,_2m\dfrac{57(2n-1)^2+1}2\\
(m,n)\in\mathbb N^2,\quad (s^\,_1,s^\,_2)\in\{-1,1\}^2,
\end{cases}$$
or
$$\begin{cases}
x^2-z^2 = s^\,_1m(2n-1)\\
4y^2=m(57n^2-57n+14)\\
3x^2-19z^2=s^\,_2m(114n^2-114n+29)\\
(m,n)\in\mathbb N^2,\quad (s^\,_1,s^\,_2)\in\{-1,1\}^2.
\end{cases}\tag2$$

$\color{brown}{\mathbf{Cases\ "+ +","- +".}}$

$$
\begin{cases}
x^2-z^2 = s^\,_1m(2n-1)\\
4y^2=m(57n^2-57n+14)\\
3x^2-19z^2=m(114n^2-114n+29)\\
(m,n)\in\mathbb N^2
\end{cases}\Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
x^2-z^2 = s^\,_1m(2n-1)\\
3x^2-8y^2-19z^2 = m\\
3x^2+8y^2-19z^2 = 57m(2n-1)^2.
\end{cases}\tag3$$

From $(3)$ should
$$6x^2\equiv 3y^2\equiv m\pmod{19},$$

with the single solution
$$6x^2\equiv 3y^2\equiv m \equiv 0.\tag4$$
(see [Wolfram Alpha tables](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=table%20%7B%286n%5E2%29%20mod%2019%2C%20%283n%5E2%29%20mod%2019%7D%2C%20%7Bn%2C0%2C18%7D))

Let $(x_0,y_0,z_0,m_0,n_0)$ is the solution with the least norm $N(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2.$

Then from $(4)$ should
$$x_0 = 19x_1,\quad y_0 = 19y_1,\quad 19\,|\, m_0,$$
and from $(3.1)$ should
$$z_0 = 19z_1, \quad a_0 = 361 m_1.$$

Easily to see, that $(x_1,y_1,z_1,m_1,n_0)$ is another solution, with the norm
$$N(x_1,y_1,z_1) = \frac1{361}N(x_0,y_0,z_0).$$

Therefore, solution with the least positive norm does not exist, and zero solution is unique.

$\color{brown}{\mathbf{Cases\ "+ -","- -".}}$
$$
\begin{cases}
x^2-z^2 = s^\,_1m(2n-1)\\
4y^2=m(57n^2-57n+14)\\
19z^2-3x^2=m(114n^2-114n+29)\\
(m,n)\in\mathbb N^2
\end{cases}\Rightarrow
\begin{cases}
x^2-z^2 = s^\,_1m(2n-1)\\
19z^2-3x^2-8y^2 = m\\
19z^2-3x^2+8y^2 = 57m(2n-1)^2.
\end{cases}\tag5$$

From $(5)$ should
$$13x^2\equiv16\equiv m\pmod{19},$$

with the single solution
$$6x^2\equiv 3y^2\equiv m \equiv 0\tag6$$
(see [Wolfram Alpha table](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=table%20%7B%2813n%5E2%29%20mod%2019%2C%20%2816n%5E2%29%20mod%2019%7D%2C%20%7Bn%2C0%2C18%7D))

and the similar proof.

$\color{brown}{\mathbf{Proved.}}$

Answer (score 2):

COMMENT.- Just for fun. Do you have for the equation $3x^4+7y^4=19z^4$ the following irrational parameterization
$$\begin{cases}x=\left(\sqrt[4]{\dfrac{19}{3}}\sqrt{\dfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}}\right)z\\y=\left(\sqrt[4]{\dfrac{19}{7}}\sqrt{\dfrac{2t}{1+t^2}}\right)z\end{cases}$$ There is a value of $t$ such that both  $\sqrt[4]{\dfrac{19}{3}}\sqrt{\dfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}}$ and $\sqrt[4]{\dfrac{19}{7}}\sqrt{\dfrac{2t}{1+t^2}}$ be rational $\ne0$?

If the equation $3x^4+7y^4=19z^4$ is not solvable, certainly NOT. But if the equation is solvable, certainly YES.  For example for the equation $10x^4+6y^4=285z^4$ we have the parameterization $$\begin{cases}x=\left(\sqrt[4]{\dfrac{285}{10}}\sqrt{\dfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}}\right)z\\y=\left(\sqrt[4]{\dfrac{285}{6}}\sqrt{\dfrac{2t}{1+t^2}}\right)z\end{cases}$$ and for $t=\pm\dfrac15\sqrt{\dfrac{179\pm12\sqrt{114}}{5}}$ (which is root of $125t^4-358t^2+125=0$) we get the solution $(x,y,z)=(3,5,2)$.

Comment: The parametric form in t looks like $\tan{\frac{\theta}{2}}$ substitution in place of sine and cosine.

Comment: @Random: It was exactly what you say. It was to avoid non-algebraic functions. Note that in this way the solvability of $ax^4 + by^4 = cz^4$ can be characterized. Unfortunately this criteria would not be very useful.